# border-radius issues in IE 9, 8 , 7

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have attached the image below of the menu which i am using for my site , Apart from IE , all the other browsers renders the correct output :

[image]

Even in IE9 the hover effect should be curvy but it comes up with rectangular effect .

Firefox , safari , and chrome works fine :
[image]

Css

```
header nav {
padding:7px 0 10px 0;
}
header nav ul {
float:right;
padding:2px 0 0 0;
}
header nav ul li {
  float:left;
  padding-left:4px;
  }
  header nav ul li a {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'ColaborateThinRegular';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    height:32px;
    line-height:32px;
    background-color:#181717;
    padding:0 36px 0 10px;
    border-radius:17px;
    -moz-border-radius:17px;
    -webkit-border-radius:17px;
    }
  header nav ul li a:hover,
  header nav ul li a.current {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E53088, #E530C1); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #E53088),color-stop(1, #E530C1)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#E53088', endColorstr='#E530C1'); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#E53088', endColorstr='#E530C1')"; /* IE8 */
border-radius:17px;
    -moz-border-radius:17px;
    -webkit-border-radius:17px;

    }
```

I am looking for the same behaviour like firefox, chrome and safari

Comment: `border-radius` is a css3 feature whereas IE6/7/8 are pre-css3 era browsers.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the css which i am using , i just uploaded it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient filter in Internet Explorer doesn't get clipped by the `border-radius` in Internet Explorer 9.  The only solution I can think of involves having an inner `<div>` element with the gradient applied:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="gradient">Home</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Apply the `border-radius` to the `<li>` element and the gradient to `<div class="gradient">`.  This should give the correct result.

The only other option, as Salman A mentioned, is [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which work around this problem for you ***and*** implement `border-radius` in older versions of IE.  I'm using this in a couple of projects and it works very well.

Comment: is this a bug in IE , y do we always have to use hacks to sort out IE issues , why they dont make it simple like chrome ..

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like it might be an IE9 bug. The other browsers have been through this kind of issue with border-radius in the past (eg Firefox 3.0 didn't clip the corners of an `<img>` tag with border radius), so if this is an IE bug then its frustrating that IE hasn't learnt from the mistakes of others.

Comment: @Spudley: I believe it's just because filters are out of date.  They don't appear to get updated with each version of IE, which could also explain why the alpha issues were never fixed with other filters.  A filter just sees an elements dimensions and repaints a rectangle in place of the element (similar to how binary behaviours work).  I wouldn't be surprised if filters were deprecated or even defunct in IE 11.

Comment: @AndyE - That was my first thought too, but the issue is in IE9, and IE9 doesn't use the `filter` styles.

Comment: @Spudley: you're right, they are deprecated according to the docs :-) However, `-ms-filter` is still required for gradients in IE 9 as it doesn't support `linear-gradient` natively.  IE 10 does.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) project. It will make various CSS3 features available in IE 6 through 9; including rounded corners.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the css which i am using , i just uploaded it

Comment: I just looked at your CSS and I am sure CSS3 PIE will make the `linear-gradient` and `border-radius` properties work in older versions of IE. Open the demo on project's homepage in IE and see if it gives you the expected results.

Comment: +1 CSS3Pie is excellent for this sort of thing, and will fix your IE7/8 issues. (not sure about the IE9 problem you have; that's a separate issue entirely)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.class {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
}
```

just a quick example

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the css which i am using , i just uploaded it

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap does the following to solve this issue:

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);`